# How should I handle 3rd party IDP delete callbacks with Cognito users?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm looking at implementing Facebook with a Cognito user pool. I also have a dynamodb user entry that contains the cognito id associated with the user.

Facebook requires a data deletion callback endpoint where they pass the Facebook id of the user.

I could create a lambda, but I don't know which Cognito user is associated with the Facebook id.

This seems like this would be a pretty common thing that people have done in the past, but I've not found any good documentation of cleaning up users when permissions are revoked for any IDP.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the user by `username` attribute. According to Cognito documentation Facebook's `id` is mapped to `username` in Cognito.

```
Currently, only the Facebook `id`, Google `sub`, Login with Amazon `user_id`, and Sign in with Apple `sub` attributes can be mapped to the Amazon Cognito User Pools `username` attribute.
```

Apart from the ID you already store in DynamoDB, you also need to add `username`. Then you will be able to find the corresponding user.

Comment: Thanks. It's unfortunate Cognito doesn't have a way of handling the callbacks from the IDPs themselves.